# Can TypeScript Compiler API resolve the value of an expression?

Tags: typescript, abstract-syntax-tree, typescript-compiler-api

I'm wondering if there is a way to resolve the final value for an expression (using the TypeScript compiler API) that would work in a way similar to getTypeAtLocation.

Take the following example:

```
const g = {
    a: 'hello'
}

export enum wonkyEnum {
  A, // = 0
  B = 1,
  C = g['a'] as any, 
  D = "str" as any
  E = [ ...[1,2,3] ][2]
}
```

- In this example, C, D, and E will not work with getConstantValue().
- D is easy to parse, however, **C** and **E** are examples of deeper problems due to the expressions used, reference, etc.

My hope is that there is even a partial solution which will not require writing an involved recursive parser which covers all possible contingencies for an initializer expression. If nothing is exposed in TS, 3rd party open-source code could also be useful.

Otherwise, any detail which would help me to know all possible node variations in this place would help!

I already have a robust recursive parser system in place, which I am using primarily for walking Type structure, but it can be implemented for Node / Kind, also. I mostly would like to be sure that I'm not cluttering up the code unnecessarily or reinventing the wheel before going that route.

Thanks!

## Edit

David's answer below is correct - there isn't a means to do it with TS.

In exploring it further, to cover all cases, actual evaluation would be required. This could get messy and be impossible in many cases (see comments below).

Fortunately, in the case of enums, TypeScript appears to generally be able to get the answer with the getConstantValue() method.

As a fallback, we'll recursively parse initializer node covering a few expression cases (as follows):

```
// key is tested for node.kind equality in parseInitializer()
const valueParsers = Map<number | number[], (node: any) => string | number | boolean | null>([
  [SyntaxKind.TrueKeyword, () => true],
  [SyntaxKind.FalseKeyword, () => false],
  [SyntaxKind.NullKeyword, () => null],
  [SyntaxKind.StringLiteral, (node: LiteralLikeNode) => node.text],
  [
    [SyntaxKind.AsExpression, SyntaxKind.ParenthesizedExpression, SyntaxKind.TypeAssertionExpression],
    (node: any) => parseInitializer(node.expression) // recursive call
  ],
]);
```

If anyone has any ideas at broadening it a bit without going too crazy, feel free to comment below!

Comment: Not sure why you'd need to do any parsing if you already have an abstract syntax tree.

Comment: It seems like you are going to run into evaluating arbitrary JavaScript code... So... get the emitted text and just call `eval`?

Comment: @Gerrit0 that would work, but they would probably want to run a quick check on the nodes to ensure all the descendants are self contained (ex. works for `[1, 2, 3][2]`, but not `[a, b, c][1]`... that may accidentally work if those variables were defined in the executing code)

Comment: @kaya3 I meant "parsing" in the sense of walking the tree for a final value.

Comment: @Gerrit0 I think you're right. The same just occurred to me. It might be reasonable to get the symbols and call eval, but then there is also the concern that something evaluated is very expensive, writes to disk, etc. Or it could require DB connection, etc, so it wouldn't be possible during AST parsing to determine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is useful to do, but the compiler doesn't have anything built in for resolving expression values. It's not concerned with that... the `getConstantValue` on the type checker is specifically for enum members.

I also don't believe there is any library to help do this at the moment... at least I haven't seen one. Perhaps you or someone else would like to create one? That would be a fun project!

Anyway, these are just my high level thoughts that would work, but could be improved on:

**Finding Property Assignment Value**

It's kind of hard to do this because you would have to check if something modified `g.a` before it is assigned to the enum member:

```
const g = { a: 'hello' };
g.a = 'other string';
```

If you really want to implement something like that, then I believe one way to do that is to get the symbol of `g.a` (`getSymbolAtLocation`), then from there look at the property assignment in the `#valueDeclaration` property. From that property assignment, you'll have to walk the nodes in the tree down in order to get the last assignment to that property before the enum member declaration (some person looking for trouble might reassign the property in a previous enum member initializer). If the assignment expression is a constant or some expression you can resolve then you know the value. If it's not, then you'll have to go to that declaration and walk the tree from there. Basically, it starts getting really complicated and you won't always be able to determine the value statically.

Perhaps a limitation of your analyzer might be that string types aren't allowed in which case a const assertion should be used?

```
const g = { a: 'hello' } as const;
```

In that case, `getTypeAtLocation` for `a` in `g.a` is the `"hello"` string literal type.

**Nested Arrays**

For these nested arrays `[ ...[1,2,3] ][2]` you could walk the tree in post order, resolve the array items, flatten the array due to the spread syntax, then get the third item in the array. Perhaps knowing it is only looking for the third item you could optimize that and only resolve enough to get the second item (could be a big time saver if the array is something like `[...[g.a, 2, 3]]`).

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts! It turns out the spread can resolve, and TS provides reasonable constraints unless 'as any' is specified, so I'm less concerned. Users would be deliberately subverting standard enum constraints with as any.

One thing that occurred to me is that there would be scenarios that would simply be missed even with the best node parsing. 

For example: E = myObj[(() => Object.keys(myObj).filter(k => k === 'myKey'))()] - an admittedly contrived scenario, but it does make me realize that evaluation would be needed in a lot of scenarios.

Comment: Oh yeah, there's all kinds cases that would need to be handled and in many cases it would be impossible to know. Are you sure that `[ ...[1,2,3] ][2]` works? I get `undefined` when I try passing that enum member to `getConstantValue` and I don't see anything in the compiler's code for handling that though I might not be looking hard enough.

Comment: Edit: Nevermind. I had the wrong value! You're right.

Comment: I believe if you make the enum a `const enum` in the editor then it should show all the scenarios where `getConstantValue` works (by not having a compile error on those members).

Comment: That's a great idea. Thanks. The use-case here is a library which parses types and generates JSON schema. Differences in this library are it relies entirely on TypeChecker (aside from enum) and preserves TypeAliases as references. Its default use is as a plugin, so it emits *.schema.json files during tsc compile. Can be used programmatically also. That in mind, I think it's reasonable to add a small note on the readme about the edge-case limitation on enum.

Comment: Or perhaps even just throwing a warning if we can't get a value would be better.